Trying to understand video conversion, difference
Downloaded YouTube video in 240 quality, as well as 1080.
I took 1080 as the input file, executed this command:
ffmpeg -i /1080p.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx264 -vf scale=-2:240,fps=30 -ab 128k /1_240.mp4

Data, file quality 240 from YouTube
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2023-06-25T18:46:33.000000Z
  Duration: 00:03:05.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 133 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 426x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40], 1 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-06-25T18:46:33.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Data from a 240 file that was converted from a 1080 YouTube file:
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.65.100
  Duration: 00:03:05.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 294 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 426x240 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9], 291 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

There is a difference in bitrate; YouTube’s bitrate is two times lower. I can’t set the bitrate because YouTube doesn’t allow it either.
If you take 2 videos on YouTube and select 144 quality, look at the bitrate. It’s completely different.
There are still differences:
YouTube
yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive)
426x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40]
1 kb/s

At the exit
yuv420p(tv, bt709)
426x240 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9]
291 kb/s

As a result, the filesize is 2-3 times larger.
I'm trying to make sure that the filesize of my 240 quality is no more than on YouTube.
What can I fix in my stream in order to get a video with the same data and compare the filesize with the file from YouTube?

Can't you set the video bitrate when encoding? Add -vb 144k argument:  ffmpeg -i 1080p.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx264 -vf scale=-2:240 -vb 144k -ab 128k 1_240.mp4 (note: using fps=30 is usually not recommended, because it skips of duplicates frames, unless the input is exactly 60fps).

I downloaded 5 different files of the same quality from YouTube. Each file has a different bitrate.

If you specify a fixed bitrate in the command. In some cases (often), the weight of the files will be greater compared to YouTube.

I want to understand how YouTube does this. As he indicates the bitrate, then when each quality (take 144 from five publications) has its own bitrate.

That is, on YouTube they do not explicitly indicate the bitrate during conversion. They do not lose quality at a lower birate and gain in quality

Setting the bitrate is not recommended, and not what YouTube does. If you download five YouTube videos from five different sources, they will all be at different bitrates. I suspect YouTube uses -crf (or similar, codec dependent) to set the quality rate. The default value is 23, and I suspect YouTube probably use a value of 25/26. This means that simpler videos can be lighter and more complex videos will be heavier to support the complexity.
